# WKWebView+contentInset makes content size wrong

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

On iOS, when you set a `contentInset` on a `WKWebView`'s scroll view, it seems to make the web view think the content of the page is bigger than it is. For example, if you give a mostly-empty page a top or bottom `contentInset`, you'll be able to scroll the page down even though there's nothing to scroll to.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a workaround that still allows me to use `contentInset`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that `WKWebView` always seems to use its frame as its viewport size, neglecting to subtract the scrollView's `contentInset`. I was able to find a [workaround](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1135814) by [stephan-leroux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603497/stephan-leroux).

The idea is to set the WKWebView's frame to the desired viewport size, either manually or using autolayout constraints. To restore the "scroll-under" effect of `contentInset`, disable the scrollView's `masksToBounds`:

```
wkWebview.scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

weiyin's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35472603/193896) (resizing the web view's frame) worked for me.

Just wanted to share a code example:

```
CGFloat topInset = ...;
web.scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
[web.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, 0, 0, 0)];
[web setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, web.width, web.height-topInset)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Four years later and the problem still persists...

[weiyin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35472603/2062785) works great, but if you're like me you might struggle a bit with figuring out what exactly to do (though it's really quite simple).

#### So here's a simple explanation for dummies (like me):

1. Embed your *Web View* inside a *Wrapper View*.
2. Size and position your *Web View* in a way that its frame is inset from the *Wrapper View* precisely by your desired content inset.
3. Set `clipsToBounds = false` on the *Web View's* scroll view (and `true` on the *Wrapper View*).
4. Make sure that there is no content inset set on the *Web View* (`webview.contentInset = .zero`).

   (This is the default and normally, you don't need to set it at all).

#### Done:

- **100% content inset behavior on the *Web View* without *using* content insets.**

[image: Visual explanation of how to arrange the views]

Comment: And the scrollbar is... 8pts to the left .(

Comment: @Zoltán You can always move it back: [horizontalScrollIndicatorInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/3198044-horizontalscrollindicatorinsets).